# PHP and File authorization

Tags: php, mysql

Looking to see if the following is possible.

I have a PHP site, that allows for users to have a basic login to the site with their login information stored in a MYSQL database.

Through the administration area of the site, I can upload PDFs that all get uploaded to a specific folder. For example, I'll say the location is "/pdf/uploads/".

Is it possible to restrict what user can see a certain file?

For example, let's say I have a user with the username "jsmith". They login and see a file listed "test.pdf" that is stored in the /pdf/uploads/ directory. They are allowed to open the file by clicking on the link.

Then a 2nd user, "jdoe" logs in, and he sees files that are listed for him, but doesn't see the "test.pdf" file listed that jsmith does. If "jdoe" randomly types in the url "http://www.website.com/pdf/uploads/test.pdf", is there a way to not allow him to view/download that file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes this is certainly possible!

Comment: I suggest building a PDF server in PHP which will validate PDF files against authentication rights. Then only serve the files that are available for a particular user. However, you'll get the best results by doing a little research, showing us an attempt, and telling us what went wrong.

Comment: OP is looking for a developer who does this for him. I doubt OP is asking *how* rather than gimmetahcodez.

Comment: @wesley: because you can either give a man a fish and they eat for a day; or you teach them to fish, and they eat for life. we prefer teaching to fish. better to learn the concepts, instead of just being a "gimme the codez" begger.

Comment: @MarcB He's not asking for code, he's asking for an angle. I'm sure a helpful answer could include zero code, with the exception of a couple manual links. Sure, I get it though.

Comment: I apologize for not being a PHP genius. I am an amateur developer trying to figure out the logic of how something like this would work. I don't appreciate comments saying I'm looking for a "gimmie the code", I'm trying to understand the logic and to see if what I'm requesting is actually doable. Obviously I don't know, so this is why I'm here asking for some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. All you have to do is to check current user permission and `readfile()` with proper headers.

Eg. like this:

```
$file = 'somefolder/file.pdf';

if (file_exists($file) && userHasPermission($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    die;
}
```

Also it's good to put this files above public directory. In that way noone can be able to access it in other way than through that script (of ftp of course).

Comment: This is what I do, and it's fine, but I'm still looking for a better/other way. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @WesleyMurch What isn't good enough in that method? I don't think there is something better in PHP. Especially when you want to hide real file and check permissions.

Comment: I guess you're right. I always felt like there should be some other way. Actually I feel better now, thanks.

Comment: So to clarify, that code would go on the page that would display all the files available to that user. But what if anyone else, even someone not logged in, would just happen to type in the path to a file, "http://www.website.com/pdf/uploads/test.pdf". As far as my understanding goes, the PDF would just open in the browser. Is there a way to prevent that or no?

Comment: @user2762748 Read last lines from my answer.

Comment: On a test file, named "test.php" I placed the above code, modified to the location of the folder.

When someone goes to "test.php", instead of trying to download the PDF file, it's prompting me to either open or save the actual "test.php" file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. But you will have to save this information about permissions in the database too. I think you need more 2 tables:

- files
- user_files

so you can register the files on the files table and associate the users with respective files in user_files table.